# Need to find out if an item is seasonal if 70% of the 12 month sales fall within 4 consecutive months

Tags: excel, excel-2013

I used the large function to tell me the 4 largest months but still cant figure out how to test if they are in consecutive months ... unless you guys know a overall better formula ..

Comment: you need to put more data in your question. Not able to make anything out from your question

Answer (score 0):

For four integers say in A1:A4 to be consecutive:

```
=MAX(A1:A4)-MIN(A1:A4)=3
```

Since seasonality might span a year end you might want to add say 12 to the actual month number each time the year increments (so if January 2016 is `1`, December2016 would be `12`, and the first quarter of 2017 might be `13`, `14` and `15`, thus maintaining a sequence across year end).